# How to determine from which row a jQuery function is called

Tags: jquery, html

I want to collect all data from `<td>'s` in a certain row. I have limited knowledge about `jQuery` so I try to work myself through from the more general thing to what I exactly need.

For now I have this simple [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GzWuP/) to illustrate what I mean. I create a table dynamically, according to a data from a database so one row may contain from 1 to many `<td>..</td>` and in each `<td>` I have an `<input../>` control that holds some value. The ultimate goal is to be able to let the user edit a given row and then to Update (collect the values from all inputs and send them to the server) the edited data.

As you can see in my `JsFiddle` example I figured out how to collect all the data using `$('td').each(function()` but of course this is not what I want. I want only the data from which the `getData()` function was called. Which leads to the first problem that I can't resolve (at least in a proper way).

What I know is that if nothing else I can give each `<tr>` some unique `id` so I can easily select it with `jQuery`. However since I'm calling the function on click event from anchor inside a `<td>` of the same row I'm pretty sure that there should be a way to determine the row without giving it unique `id` and passing it as argument to the `getData()` function but I couldn't find a way to do it. So is it really possible to determine the row without using special identifier and if so could you help me with the code for the `jQuery` function to select the row for/from which the `getData()` funciton was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.parent()` to get the parent. You have to use it twice to get to the tr.
change your onclick to :

```
`onclick="getData(this)"
```

`
and your getData to:

```
function getData(elem) {
 alert( $(elem).parent().parent().find('input').val() );
};
```

you can see the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/GzWuP/5/

Comment: Hmm, what is the problem with `$(elem.parentNode).parent()` ? I've just tested it in my original code and I got the expected result, in other words it seems to work. What is the difference?

Comment: Its fine, but its weird to mix native Js and Jquery more then neccessary ;)

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. And forgive me the noob question but using `this` when I call `onclick="getData(this)" I am actually passing the `<a>` attribute is that right?

Comment: yes, that's why you need to use .parent() twice. You could also pass this.parentNode.parentNode here. And leave out the .parent().parent() in getData(). But its more convenient to have the element that was clicked on, in case you want to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get tr 
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        //Find input
        var input = tr.find('input');
        alert(input.val());
    });
});
```

You could assign an ID or something to your table as you create it to provide a traversal cue, which would be perfectly valid.

The above is a different solution, whereby each and every anchor gets a handler attached to its `click` event. What we want to do is a little snooping around the anchor to find the `input` of interest.

First, we find the grandparent of the link we clicked, which we know will be a table row: `var tr = $(this).parent().parent();`

Now, we just need to a dig a bit further to find the relevant `input` using the `find()` method:

```
var input = tr.find('input');
```

So long as your table markup is consistent, you can easily find whatever element you are looking for thanks to jQuery's DOM traversal functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/GzWuP/3/

Comment: thank you for the answer. It's working fine but `cytofu` suggestion is closer to my original idea so I'll go this way. Still your explanation was very helpful for me!

Comment: No worries. I would point out that your answer includes burning in javascript code onto your HTML elements, which isn't ideal. It's considered a better practice to attach handlers from an external script file.